# How to reduce the output capacitance?

Tags: analog

How to reduce the output capacitance at the drain of Q2?

[image]
Thanks.

Editted
Assuming the size of the transistors should be unchanged.

Comment: Reduce the size of Q1 & Q2?

Answer (score 3):

Q1 and Q2 can be reduced in either length, width, or both to reduce the capacitance. Which to reduce depends on the other parameters of interest, but the same ought to be done to both (in order to preserve matching).

Reducing gate *width* for the same input current will increase Vds and the inversion coefficient. The capacitance will be decreased, but you may experience a loss of headroom (possibly important for low-voltage designs).

Reducing gate *length* will lead to a weaker inversion; Vds will be smaller, but Rout will also be decreased (due to short-channel effects). You will have more voltage headroom.

You may also consider reducing the two parameters while keeping the shape ratio the same; Vds will stay roughly the same but you may experience a modest decrease in output impedance with a short gate (again, due to short-channel effects)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is there any other strategy we can use if the size of both transistors are required to be kept constant.

Comment: @PhaeLeung frr's answer mentions as cascode connection which reduces Miller capacitance. Beyond that there isn't any change in parametrization (since size is fixed) or other topological tweak I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @nanofarad said, you can suppress the effect of the Miller capacitance in Q2 (between drain and gate) by cascading another N-transistor in the drain of Q2. The added transistor should have the gate attached to constant voltage = common gate connection.

--- EDIT ---

I've made some corrections based on polite feedback from Brian Drummond (typoes and general vocabulary, we're speaking FET's rather than BJT's).

As for why or how this works: note that the Miller capacitance in Q2 does not go away. The trick (before/after) depends on the typical "before" situation where the D of Q2 works against a pull-up resistor (or a constant current source), and therefore faces some resulting AC voltage amplitude. This connection is typical for voltage-coupled topologies. And, these voltage fluctuations get coupled back from Q2's drain to Q2's gate. Then, in our "after" situation, an added cascode transistor (Q3?) with a constant gate voltage tends to stabilize voltage at the Drain of Q2. Which reduces the amount of energy coupled back to Q2's gate via Miller capacitance. You might argue, that Q3 has merely taken over the burden of Miller capacitance from Q2, and now Q3 will suffer from its undesired effects, between its D and G. Thats true - except that a constant voltage source can be made with a fairly low impedance at Q3 gate, so that the Miller capacitance in Q3 doesn't matter nearly as much.

The topology of the current mirror can be further improved upon. Check Hans Camenzinds's free book called [Designing Analog Chips](http://www.designinganalogchips.com/), chapter 3 on current mirrors. Specifically, the Wilson Current Mirror improvement.

Comment: common-gate (or grid) I think. aka cascode connection.

Comment: @frr Thanks for all your reply. May I ask for more explanation why a casocde current mirror can reduce Miller capacitance? Thanks

Comment: @frr Thanks for your editted reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just a small region of operation, then positive feedback loads (cross-coupled Pfets) may be useful.

Or a gyrator approach.